# Do you think my dogs are exercised enough?

Tags: dogs, exercise

I have four technically high energy dogs, two Canaan, one German Shepherd and a Shi Zu jack russell terrier mix.....all rescued, here in Cairo.  I feel I am not giving them enough.  I am a teacher and have a fairly large apartment with a garden of the same dimensions which the dogs are not really interested in actually.

There is a general fear and abhorrence of dogs in this culture, generally.  And I have developed a phobia of going out with the whole pack as although my dogs (oi, coco, elvis and Fat girl) are wonderfully natured and social, I have been arrested many times purely because neighbors saw us and made up stories.  I still have my babes but have reduced going out with them to once a day. well at least in day light hours.

I have found a new location in a compound near to a large expanse of desert, so each morning around half four we hike around 6 kilometers through it.  The dogs go mental and run about like loons, and for the rest of the day, sleep or watch me or TV.

I wonder,

As I originate from a dogie filled family in Scotland who is used to going on massive trips for hours each day...plus a half to an hour trip off the lead in the evening, I mean are these dogs being tolerant and suffering or are really actually OK?

Answer (score 5):

I'd say you answered your own question right with this sentence:

> ...and for the rest of the day, sleep or watch me or TV.

If your dogs would have to burn more energy, they wouldn't do that.

We've got two Huskies (so even more energy) and you can easily tell that they've got too much energy left for the day once they start running/playing inside the house in the evening.

Dogs with too much energy won't just sit around watching you.

Comment: I agree with Mario. I think you're already doing more than a lot of people do already. If you aren't having a lot of behavioral problems and the dogs seem content to lay around otherwise, I'd say they're being exercised enough.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're doing just fine based on your situation. A 6 km walk is plenty of exercise, and seems like you want to do more but your situation prevents you from doing so. If they're well behaved and calm at home, it seems like they're getting out the energy they need to in order to be relaxed the rest of the day. Ideally every dog would spend hours outside each day playing, but the reality is that everyone does the best they can based on their individual circumstances. I wouldn't worry too much if I were you.